# How are properties created and referenced at at the same time with this. keyword in constructor? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, properties, this

I don't understand how properties are created in a class constructor with the this. keyword. Shouldn't they be defined before, and then referenced to with the this. keyword? How is this. used to reference property that doesn't already exist? I have some basic knowledge in Java and didn't met this situation before. Thanks.
Heres an example:

```
class Dog{
  constructor(name){
     this.name = name;
     this.behavior = 0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript and Java are different languages. In Javascript you can declare anything anywhere. `this.something = ...` declares a property `something` in the object refered to by `this`. In a way you can imagine Javascript classes like Java maps, where the `.`-operator acts like `put` or `get`.